# present self.presentingViewController to the foreground

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have ViewControllers A and B in the code.

A presents B when I press a button. Then in B I add a navigation bar which has a navigation item called "Back to previous screen". Then I try to do this logic: when press the navigation item, execute the following code to go back to B's presentingViewController, which, in this case I think it is A.

```
[self presentViewController:self.presentingViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But unfortunately A doesn't show up. I use "print [self.presentingViewController class]" command in lldb and I can see the class is A. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "A presents B" by presentViewController:animated:completion: then you can back to A by something like this:

```
- (void) back: (id)sender
{
  [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why You not added `UINavigationController` To **"A"** ?? It is more better and Easy then your Logic.

Just Follow my code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.AViewController = [[AViewController alloc] init];
    self.navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.AViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navCon;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know. But I don't want the UINavigationController to show on my first page. Apart from that I also want to know why my code is not working because the logic seems to be fine.